# preferred language not importing with contact data

Tags: import, language

I have tried this several ways, but can't seem to get the preferred language to come in with the contact import. The initial values I had were basic (English, French, etc.) and didn't match the labels in Civi. I changed them to match the Civi labels, with no luck and finally, have tried simply using the assigned values: en, es, etc.  Still no luck.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that a country designation is required too, even though they are not easily shown in the prefered language interface. So fr is not valid, but fr_FR is.

Comment: Yes. It uses locale code not just language and should match the name of the .po file .   http://userguide.icu-project.org/locale